# Time Complexity: Determining if a binary tree is balanced

Tags: runtime-analysis, binary-search-trees, avl-trees

I found an algorithm for determining if a binary tree is height-balanced.
It Gets the height of left and right subtrees using dfs traversal. Return true if the difference between heights is not more than 1 and left and right subtrees are balanced, otherwise return false.

algorithm code:

```
/* CPP program to check if
a tree is height-balanced or not */

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/* A binary tree node has data,
pointer to left child and
a pointer to right child */
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(int d)
    {
        int data = d;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

// Function to calculate the height of a tree
int height(Node* node)
{
    // base case tree is empty
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;

    // If tree is not empty then
    // height = 1 + max of left height
    // and right heights
    return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
}

// Returns true if binary tree
// with root as root is height-balanced
bool isBalanced(Node* root)
{
    // for height of left subtree
    int lh;

    // for height of right subtree
    int rh;

    // If tree is empty then return true
    if (root == NULL)
        return 1;

    // Get the height of left and right sub trees
    lh = height(root->left);
    rh = height(root->right);

    if (abs(lh - rh) <= 1 && isBalanced(root->left)
        && isBalanced(root->right))
        return 1;

    // If we reach here then tree is not height-balanced
    return 0;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    Node* root = new Node(1);
    root->left = new Node(2);
    root->right = new Node(3);
    root->left->left = new Node(4);
    root->left->right = new Node(5);
    root->left->left->left = new Node(8);

    if (isBalanced(root))
        cout << "Tree is balanced";
    else
        cout << "Tree is not balanced";
    return 0;
}
```

Claimed this code has `O(n^2)` complexity but I can not understand why.
I think the worst case is when the Binary Tree is full, and in this case, the height of BST is `log n` that in every level it runs the `height` function with `O(n)` complexity.
So I think I must have `O(n log n)` time complexity.

Comment: (Tag [runtime-analysis](/tags/runtime-analysis/info).) Note that every function in $O(n\log n)$ is in $O(n^2)$, too. Succinct *pseudo code* is preferred here over somewhat verbose code in a somewhat verbose programming language. *Who* claimed $O(n^2)$? What is the complexity for a completely degenerate tree, say, only left children?

Comment: Sure every function in O(n log n)
 is in O(n^2). But we expected lowest bound. GeeksForGeeks claimed O(n^2).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/

Comment: See, the answer is in your link, your code is $O(n^2)$, while there is an $O(n)$ alternative code there. You said it yourself `the height of BST is log n that in every level it runs the height function with O(n) complexity`, we are calculating time complexity so we care about the height function complexity, not height itself.

Comment: Please replace your C++ code with concise pseudocode.  We are not a coding site and I expect that questions about a bunch of code are likely off-topic here.  Not everyone here reads C+++ code, and asking someone to read all of that code is asking a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Determining if a binary tree is balanced runs in $O(n)$, since we only need to traverse each node once, and moving from one node to another requires $O(1)$ moves.

However, since your code calculates height from scratch repeatedly, it runs in $O(n^2)$.